# AWS Elastic Beanstalk File Upload Limit Issue

Tags: upload, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I'm having an issue on an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance, whereby I can't seem to upload a PDF file that is 6MB in size. First, let me provide a bit more background:

- The application running is an Expression Engine (EE) application
- upload_max_filesize is set to 16M
- post_max_size is set to 32M
- max_execution_time is set to 300
- Files are being uploaded through the EE application on Elastic Beanstalk into an Amazon S3 bucket.

I am able to successfully upload PDFs in the region of 1-2MB, but when I try to upload the 6MB file it reaches 100% uploaded and then redirects me back to the home screen in EE and the file has not been uploaded.

Does anyone know or have any ideas why I wouldn't be able to upload the 6MB file, given that the config variables above are set as such?

Comment: take a look at a similar question - [Increasing client_max_body_size in Nginx conf on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18908426/1429387).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using NGINX or other proxy server, it may be related to it's `client_max_body_size` directive. To fix it create folder `.ebextensions` in app root, and a file `.ebextensions/01_nginx.config`. Then tell build script to add this directive while building your environment, adding this to your created `.ebextensions/01_nginx.config`:

```
container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "service nginx reload"
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
      mode: "000755"
      owner: root
      group: root
      content: |
        client_max_body_size 25M;
```

**Commit your folder to git**, if you're using it. Then `eb deploy`, cross fingers and try to upload your 6MB PDF.

However, according to my experience, sometimes you have to completely rebuild entire environment to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is still struggling with this, check out [this SO post's first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73834114/6105926).

In my case, the build step only copied the `.build` folder to ElasticBeanstalk, thus I had to add the step `- cp -R .platform ./build/.platform` to my `buildspec.yml`'s build steps in order for the .platform folder to get copied over as well.